# Remove empty strings from a list of strings on each row in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and one of the columns contains a list of strings e.g:

['', 'Hello', 'The house is warm', '', 'What time is it']

The strings are different for each row of the dataframe but all lists on each row contain empty strings. How can I remove these?

The column is called 'Description'.

I have tried the following methods:

```
df['Description'] = df['Description', [i for i in df['Description'] if i]]
```

```
while("" in df['Description']):
    df['Description'].remove("")
```

```
df['Description'] = [list(filter(None, sublist)) for sublist in df['Description']]
```

But none work. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create new list and append only string that is not empty

use `eval()` if they are string representation of list

```
df['Description'] = df['Description'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in eval(x) if item != ''])
```

Comment: That gives the same issue as some of the methods I've already tried. I'm not sure why but it keeps separating every string into individual characters and making them their own string. So 'Escape' becomes 'E', 'S', 'C', 'A', 'P', ''E

Comment: It seems that the column contains string representation of list, right? If yes, you require to convert them to list first (e.g., `ast.literal_eval`).

Comment: okay that makes sense, how would implement that into the code you gave above?

Comment: Is this smth you are looking for? `df['Description'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x))`

Answer (score 0):

Your original idea of using `list(filter())` will work. You use `pd.Series.apply()` to do the same thing to every item in a series.

```
df['Description'].apply(lambda x: list(filter(None, x)))
```